# CKEditor custom build from source incl. certain ticket fix

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need to have new feature that was completed in http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10931 (Allow nesting widgets) in the build.

I know that it allows various ACF bugs to appear since ACF doesn't currently filter widgets within widgets, but I think we can live with it while waiting for 4.5 to arrive.

Should it work by checking out Major branch from https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev and doing a build on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branch you mentioned is **unstable and not recommended for production** ([see the REDAME](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/README.md)).

> This repository contains the following branches:
>
> - master: development of the upcoming minor release.
> - major: development
>     of the upcoming major release.
> - stable: latest stable release tag point
>     (non-beta). 
>     *latest: latest release tag point (including betas).
> - release/A.B.x (e.g. 4.0.x, 4.1.x): release freeze, tests and tagging.
>     Hotfixing.

Even though some features have already been merged into `master` or `major`, they're not production-ready until released. This is because of unpredicted interactions between plugins and possible bugs (regressions), which are detected during comprehensive testing phase, once the code is frozen.

There's always a risk that the feature is broken or the API will change, making migration to stable version of CKEditor complicated in the future. Of course, you can build CKEditor package out of unstable branch, i.e. with [ckeditor-presets](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-presets) tool, but I don't recommend using it in production environment.

Also note that building a package based on `major` means including [other features an fixes awaiting final testing in upcoming release](http://dev.ckeditor.com/query?status=closed&group=status&milestone=CKEditor%204.5.0), which may broke your application even more. Since http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10931 is quite complex, extracting related commits only may be quite tricky in your case.

Comment: I'm completely aware of the possible problems and willing to take the gamble. We need said feature to use couple of widgets together.

Another takes care of responsive rows ( getbootstrap.com ) and another adds icons ( http://fontawesome.io/ ) and we would like to have icons in our content.

I guess I could use fakeobjects as a workaround but it makes using ::before -pseudo elements a bit harder.

Any unofficial estimate on 4.5 release plans (summer maybe)?

Comment: Ended up doing this feature with fakeobjects after all.

Based on this plugin http://ckeditor.com/addon/fontawesome not the best implementation but good enough.